# How to assign values to a jQuery slider from a dropdown menu after querying a database

Tags: php, jquery

In my application, I used 3 jQuery slide bars to show 3 options. Those options are the contrast, volume and brightness of a TV, and I used them to change the TV's respective effects. I already created a database for those attributes for each client and created the communication between the server and client. After setting 3 of those values, I update my database in another action file. However, what I need is to show users on the server side to see what the current value is of those 3 attributes of my sliders. There is a dropdown menu for choosing the client, so after choosing a client, users should see what the current setup on the server is.

I just can't figure how to do this. Any help or idea would be really helpful.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 63,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {          
                $("#amount").val("" + ui.value);    
            },
            change: function(event, ui) { 
                $('#volume').attr('value', ui.value);
        }});
        $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 128,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {          
                $("#ali").val("" + ui.value);   
            },

            change: function(event, ui) { 
                $('#brightness').attr('value', ui.value);
        }});
        $( "#slider-color" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 128,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {          
                $("#col").val("" + ui.value);   
            },
            change: function(event, ui) { 
                $('#color').attr('value', ui.value);
        }});
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
        $( "#ali" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
        $( "#col" ).val( $( "#slider-color" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="dumb.php">
    Display Name :
    <select Name='layout' class="selector">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","username","password");
        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db ("mydatabase" , $con);
        $select="deneme";
        if (isset ($select)&&$select!=""){
            $select=$_POST ['NEW'];
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        $list=mysql_query("SELECT display,displayid FROM display");
        while($row_list=mysql_fetch_array($list)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_list['displayid']; ?>"><?php echo $row_list['display'] ?> 
    </option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Display Group Name :
    <select Name='displaygroup' >
    <option value=""> --- Select --- </option>
    <?php
        $temp = '0';
        $list_group=mysql_query("SELECT DisplayGroupID,DisplayGroup FROM displaygroup WHERE IsDisplaySpecific = '$temp'");
        while($row_group=mysql_fetch_array($list_group)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_group['DisplayGroupID']; ?>"><?php echo $row_group['DisplayGroup'] ?> 
    </option>
    <?php       
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <div class="demo">
        <p>
            <label for="amount">Volume Level :</label>
            <input type="text" id="amount" class="size2" value="aduket" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />

        </p>
        <div id="slider-range-min"></div>
        <p>
            <label for="ali"> Brightness Level : </label>
            <input type ="text" id="ali" class="size1" name="dumb" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"/>
        <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
        <p>
            <label for="col"> Color Level : </label>
            <input type ="text" id="col" class="size1" name="dumb" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"/>

        <div id="slider-color"></div>
        <br/>
        <p>
            <label for="standbyon"> Standby On : </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="standbyon" name="standbyon" />
            <label for="standbyoff"> Standby Off : </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="standbyoff" name="standbyoff" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </div><!-- End demo -->
    <input type="hidden" id="volume" name="volume"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="brightness" name="brightness"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="color" name="color"/>
</form>
```

That is the code that runs on the server side. I need to set those attribute values with the current setup for the chosen display. However, I cant find a way.

Answer (score 0):

{ echo $row_list['display'] ?>}

should be:

{ echo $row_list['display']; ?>}

You forgot ";"

Dont forget those ";" :)

**UPDATE**

echo $row_list['display'] ?> is missing ;

Comment: well it is not the problem. I can show those display's from database without a problem by not using ";". However thanks for the response that I changed my code and added ";".

Comment: No problem :)... Its weird that you dont get an error or that the PHP is working when you dont have the ";"